# Tiles template sometimes not loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

we are using in our Spring MVC application Tiles 3. Sometimes (every 5th or 10th server start) the template isn't loaded. Only the .jsp page is shown without header and footer. Do you have any suggestions why?

The SpringConfig

```
@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix(JSP_PREFIX);
        resolver.setSuffix(JSP_SUFFIX);
        return resolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        String[] defintions = new String[] { TILES_DEF };
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(defintions);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCacheUnresolved(false);
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

The tiles-definition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions
  PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3.0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name=".mainTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/fragments/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/fragments/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/fragments/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/fragments/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>



    <definition name="vermittlerUebersicht" extends=".mainTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/vermittlerUebersicht.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

And the template.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>


    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
```

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I have 2 viewresolvers in the spring config. Because of that it is not determined from which viewresolver the request is first handled. I had to set the order of the viewresolvers. the InternalResourceViewResolver must have to lowest priority (==hight order number).